# How to flush DNS Cache on Android Programmatically using Kotlin/Java

Tags: java, android, kotlin, caching, dns

I need to flush DNS cache on a button click in my application, so that the next query to any domain is resolved from actual server and NOT from cache.

How can I do that in my Android App using Kotlin or java.
Any code snippet or third party library that can clear DNS cache will really be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: AFAIK regular apps can't do this (non-system apps or apps without root). But you could perform your own DNS request e.g. to 8.8.8.8 using DNS over https and the use the returned IP address.